What is wrong with this sentence: Die Strasse in der Stadt war voll mit Werbeplakaten
I need to know for learning purposes please.

Who says that there's something wrong with it? The question seems to be lacking  context, because the sentence itself is fine. It may be the wrong answer in a specific learning exercise though.

First off: the sentence is not wrong, but slightly unidiomatic. There is an orthographical error too.
"Die Strasse" should be "die Straße" (notice the "ß" instead of the "ss"). In German you use double consonants to shorten the vowels before thenm, e.g. "Wasser" is pronounced with a short "a", in "Kaffee" the "a" is short while the "e" is long. The "a" in "Straße" is long, though, but the "s" is stressed nevertheless. This is signified by the "ß": a long vowel followed by a strong "s". For instance:

Maße (measures, long "a" followed by a strong "s")
Masse (mass, short "a" followed by a strong "s")

(EDIT: As @HalvarF correctly pointed out "ß" isn't used in Swiss German, therefore it is "Strasse" there.)
To the sentence itself: "die Straße in der Stadt" is correct and possible but not the way you'd address the street. If it was really one street you are talking about it would rather be:

Die eine Straße in der Stadt war ...

To stress the fact that you mean one of many streets.
"Die Straße in der Stadt" has a connotation of the city having only one street:

Which street? The street in the city!

Such an answer would only make sense if there is just one street to talk about.
But if you are talking about all (or the majority of or a significant amount of) the streets in the city you'd rather use plural than singular and you'd drop the "in". You'd use a genitivus possessivus instead of a location indicator:

Die Straßen der Stadt waren voll ...

Similarly in English: rather "the streets of the city" or "the one street in the city" than "the street in the city".

Switzerland doesn't use ß, so depending on context there may not even be an orthographical error.

While "Die Straße in der Stadt war voll mit Werbeplakaten" is perfectly okay when talking colloquially, the proper grammar would be "Die Strasse in der Stadt war voll von Werbeplakaten".

Or even better, using the genitive: "Die Strasse In der Stadt war voller Werbeplakate".

Or, if not in Switzerland: Die Straße ...

DWDS doesn't mention "voll mit" to be colloquial, any source for that? https://www.dwds.de/wb/voll

@tofro: your "genitive" is in fact an (adverbial) Dativ. Genitiv: "voll des Lobes", Dativ: "voller Lob".
